# Python Documentation (:obj:`str`) vs (str)

Tags: python, string

I have been reading the this [Example Google Style Python Docstrings](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) document to understand how good Python documentation is written. But I can't understand one thing.

When documenting strings, there is this weird notation.

For example when documenting arguments, the documentation specifies they be written like :

```
Args: 
    arg1(str): The description for arg1
```

But, in some other places, the document writes something like :

```
Args: 
    param2 (:obj:`str`, optional): The second parameter.
```

In the second case, why is the string represented as `` :obj:`str` `` and not just plain `str`? Why two representations for `strings` in the first place? When do I use which?

Comment: Because there is no standard. The second option appears to use [sphinx-style annotations](http://www.sphinx-doc.org).

Comment: I'm not sure that that document you found is all that great; not when it is internally inconsistent like that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you point me to a better document

Comment: Perhaps http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/documentation/; which comes down to 'use Sphinx'.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the answer to your question is given in  [Python: Journey from Novice to Expert](https://books.google.ch/books?id=VW3WDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1084&lpg=PA1084&dq=:obj:int%20sphinx&source=bl&ots=qODgUOG6YU&sig=ukHBraSvHETaVrH6yK9-A1C_eFA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%3Aobj%3Aint%20sphinx&f=false). Apparently, if you write `:obj:str`, your [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) documentation will contain a link to the `str` object in the standard Python documentation.

By the way, this notation is not restricted to strings. In the docstrings of the `ExampleError` class in [Example Google Style Python Docstrings](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) it says:

```
Args:
    msg (str): Human readable string describing the exception.
    code (:obj:`int`, optional): Error code.
```